# Calling a method i created in a different class and it says it doesnt exist

Tags: java

I am making an RPG project for school, like simple java code. Anyway, i created a Knight class in which i created a method called getSword, in which it pulls the sword that the user chooses in a different method. The method works, but when i try to call that method which is public in another class, it says it doesnt exist.

It is probably an easy fix but I am extremely new to java and need help!

here is a link to the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i68Q.jpg

Comment: Its a method... `k.getSword()` not `k.getSword` (that would mean you have a public variable in the Knight class called getSword)

Comment: thanks man! like i said probably an easy fix XD

Comment: No Problem! Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

change `k.getSword`

to

```
k.getSword()
```

You are calling a method, not accessing variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the parentheses.

```
k.getSword
```

isn't the same as:

```
k.getSword()
```

The former `getSword` would be the way to access a member variable. The latter (`getSword()`) is the way to access a method.

Answer (score 0):

getSword is a method not a variable. So make it k.getSword()